# Bootstrap 4 columns not stacking when screen is resized

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get my head around why the divs are not stacking on top of each other when I re size the screen. 
I'm using `col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4` but the content stays in one row and doesn't even resize.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="logo-link"><img alt="Spartan Safety Logo" class="img-fluid" src="img/logo.png">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="info-center-1">
                    <div class="info-center-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone-square fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>


                    <div class="info-center-title">
                        <h6>Customer Support and Sales</h6>
                    </div>


                    <div class="info-center-text">
                        <p>0208 5275888</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="info-center-1">
                    <div class="info-center-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>


                    <div class="info-center-title">
                        <h6>Opening Hours</h6>
                    </div>


                    <div class="info-center-text">
                        <p>Mon - Fri 08:30 - 4:30</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .info {
        display: inline-flex;
        margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
}

    .logo-link img {
        max-width: 50%;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
}

    .info-center-1 {
        margin-top: 20px;
}

.info-center-icon i {
        color: #cccccc;
        display: inline-flex;
}

.info-center-title {
        margin-bottom: px;
}

.info-center-title h6 {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 22px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display: inline-flex;
}

.info-center-text p {
        font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #FF9900;
        line-height: 22px;
        display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Try merging the `info` and `row` divs, so you have one unique field with both `info row` as classes.

Comment: Please also remember that col-xs-* have been removed in Bootstrap 4. Now you have just to use col-* instead. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You should not add more divs between `.row` and `.col-`. Instead, merge both `info` and `row` so you only have one wrapper for the `col-` divs:

```
   <div class="container">
<div class="row info">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="logo-link"><img alt="Spartan Safety Logo" class="img-fluid" src="img/logo.png">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="info-center-1">
                <div class="info-center-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone-square fa-2x"></i>
                </div>


                <div class="info-center-title">
                    <h6>Customer Support and Sales</h6>
                </div>


                <div class="info-center-text">
                    <p>0208 5275888</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="info-center-1">
                <div class="info-center-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i>
                </div>


                <div class="info-center-title">
                    <h6>Opening Hours</h6>
                </div>


                <div class="info-center-text">
                    <p>Mon - Fri 08:30 - 4:30</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/34182/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a column to take the whole width of the row for a particular screen size then you should specify col-ScreenSize-12. So you should be using col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 instead. 
And also display: inline-flex; styling on class .info is making the division to be in a single line always, so remove it.